# Image on image overlay on hover with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a php sql query that will generate a lot of images, and I need a code that will overlay a semi transparent image on top of the original image on hover.

I've seen a lot of code to do this with CSS, but that will add a ton of html code that I don't think is needed. The query can return up to like 4000 results with 40x40 images and I need just one overlay image to overlay all of them (only the one hovering) on hover.

So technically, this is what I need

Javascript

```
find class or id iconoverlay
onhover overlay this transparent image
```

HTML

```
<img src="" class or id="iconoverlay" />
```

I'm currently using JQuery in my site but I'm not familiar with javascript.

Comment: Please don't ask SO to write you code...

Comment: How about you either contribute or find something better to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's some code to float a div on hovering over an element:

```
function createTooltips(elem) {
  if (!elem.getAttribute) return;
  if (elem.getAttribute('tooltip')) {

    $(elem).hover(
      function (event) {
        $('#tt').html(this.getAttribute('tooltip'));
        $('#tt').css('left',(event.pageX + 10) + 'px');
        $('#tt').css('top',event.pageY + 'px');
        $('#tt').show();
      },
      function (event) {
        $('#tt').hide();
      });

  }
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
    createTooltips(elem.childNodes[i], num);
  }
}

createTooltips(document.body[0]);
```

All you need to do then if put your img tags into the "tooltip=" attribute and add  to your page

Comment: I am trying to avoid copying the hover img src 4000+ times

Answer (score 2):

If you have a span, a or similar block tag wrapping img. You can do this:

`<a class="imgHover" href="#"><img src="" /></a>`

```
<style>
    .imgHover { display: inline-block; position: relative;}
    .imgHover:after {content:''; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000 url('MyPlaceholderURI.jpg') no-repeat center center; display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; opacity: 0; transition: opacity .5s linear; }
    .imgHover:hover:after {opacity: 1}
</style>
```

You can see this in action here:
https://codepen.io/fabioarantes89/pen/rwMqNE

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I don't need special effects, and all this code does is puts a black box over my image. I removed #000 but nothing happens.

Comment: Please see in action on CodePen.io. Here in StackOverflow I don't code any image uri.

Comment: I pretty much copied and pasted that code, however my overlay image sitll does not show up. The overlay is just a border that has a transparent center. The only thing I can think of is maybe I need full path for the image file (ie http://localhost/img/iconhover.png instead of /img/iconhover.png)

Comment: It was not a path problem for the overlay image. This is weird, I don't have any difference between your code and mine. Could it be because it is within JQuery DataTables within JQuery UI Tabs? The actual code is sitting in between <td> tags

Comment: This is the img src
<td><a href="" class="imgHover"><img src="/img/icons/wotlk/inv_sword_07.png" width="40" /></a></td>

And this is the css
.imgHover { display: inline-block; position: relative;}
.imgHover:after {content:''; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000 url('http://localhost/img/iconhover.png') no-repeat center center; display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; opacity: 0; transition: opacity .5s linear; }
.imgHover:hover:after {opacity: 1}

Comment: I used an pseudo-element to do the overlay. Some tags, don't have this feature, like IMG, this's why `<a class="imgHover"></a>` is needed.

To position the overlay over the image, the <td> in your code must be `position: relative`.

Comment: I tried changing the class name just in case there were conflicts but it still does the same thing, fade into a black box.

Comment: Yeah I'm using <a> tag for the class element.

Comment: There's another css or javascript modifying this properties and this is why isn't working.

I updated my pen(https://codepen.io/fabioarantes89/pen/rwMqNE), to be more like yours...

Comment: The problem was I was not setting background size and the dimensions of the imgHover class. Thanks!!!!